# How to pass the first JSON response in the next request's endpoint (Postman)

Tags: javascript, postman

I get this response body in my first request:

```
{
“resource-id”: “abcd-22-sxww”
}
```

I need to use the value for the above “resource-id” (which changes every few minutes and is not constant) in the next request endpoint: {{url}}/abcd-22-sxww/END-POINT

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.environment.set("resource-id", resourceid);
```

Then, in the other one:

```
const resourceid = pm.environment.get("resource-id");
```

Or use the key in the endpoint URL:

```
{{resourceId}}
```

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox/#environment-and-global-variables

Note: Updated to reflect feedback from comments.

Comment: Thanks! I used this:

Comment: var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("resourceId", jsonData["resource-id"]);

Comment: For the 1st request and used the key "resourceId" in the endpoint url as {{resourceId}} and that worked.

Comment: @MayaS
No problem, please mark the answer as accepted to help others when they search for something similar.